# How to get value counts for certain words in a dataset

Tags: python, function, loops

I want to find the value counts for certain key terms in my data frame under the review column.Its a dataset on customer reviews and I am looking for value counts of certain words.  The words that I want value counts are for these words:

```
keywords= ["big","hat",'dress',"fabric","color"]
```

Below I already made a function that will say whether each row has one of my key terms in them.  But now I need to find the value counts for the "keywords" and I am a little stuck, can anybody help?

## How to find value counts for the keywords listed below?

```
keywords= ["big","hat",'dress',"fabric","color"]

def keyword(value):
    strings = value.split()
    if any(word in strings for word in keywords):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
    shopbop['keyword_solution']=shopbop['review_mo'].apply(keyword)
```

## this just makes the new column saying if the word is in their or not.

## bonus... would also be really cool if there is a way to make a column like below but to also display in that new column row every keyword that appears in that row in the newly created column

```
def keyword(value):
    strings = value.split()
    if any(word in strings for word in keywords):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
    shopbop['keyword_solution']=shopbop['review_mo'].apply(keyword)
```

Comment: does dataframe mean a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

It would have been helpful if you had given us an example of the DataFrame you refer to, in order to not misunderstand your approach, even though, I will try with this made up DataFrame as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
data={'review_mo':['First hat big hat line with a red color dress',
                   'Second line color color color and fabric hat', 
                   'Third line without any of those keywords but fabric ',
                   'Fourth line fabric of big big big hat fabric',
                   'big big hat hat dress dress fabric fabric color color']}
values=[0,0,0,0,0]
keywords= ["big","hat",'dress',"fabric","color"]
dictionary = dict(zip(keywords, values))
data.update(dictionary)
shopbop=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['review_mo']+keywords)
```

Dataframe and keywords list must be passed as function arguments:

```
def keyword(value,shopbop,keywords):
    for key in keywords:
        shopbop.loc[shopbop['review_mo']==value,key]=len([x for x in value.split() if x==key])
```

This block gives the bonus that you asked for (or sort of) and Total value counts of key terms found in each string:

```
shopbop['review_mo'].apply(lambda x: keyword(x,shopbop,keywords))
shopbop['keyword_solution']=shopbop[keywords].sum(axis=1)
```

Display resume:

```
shopbop.loc[:, shopbop.columns != 'review_mo']

   big  hat  dress  fabric  color  keyword_solution
0    1    2      1       0      1                 5
1    0    1      0       1      3                 5
2    0    0      0       1      0                 1
3    3    1      0       2      0                 6
4    2    2      2       2      2                10
```